# Local IPCam image to html

Tags: html, ip-camera

I am planning to embed the ipcam image to html (iframe). The problem is that the ipcam software doesn't support embedding and besides that it is in a local network.

Is it possible to make the image visible from anywhere outside the network by anyone in a way that only the image is included but no the rest of the site?

Answer (score 0):

This may be very difficult because the type of setup you're explaining would most likely be on a different domain from your codebase thus bringing [Cross-site scripting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) into play. If it wasn't you could select the image element from the iframe with something as easy as

```
$('iframe').contents().find('img');
```

or

```
window.frames[iframename].document.getElementById("imgid");
```

Your best bet since this probably isn't possible, may be to load the url into an iframe, and wrapping it with a div that's the size of the image on the resulting page, and then using `overflow:hidden;`

HTML

```
<div id="iframe-wrap">
    <iframe scrolling="no" src="your/url"></iframe>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#iframe-wrap{
    width:400px; /*  width of the img */
    height:300px; /*  height of the img */
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#iframe-wrap iframe{
   width:1200px; /* width of the iframe sources container (for brevity) */
   height:500px; /*  adjust accordingly  */
   position:absolute; 
   top:-100px; /* adjust so image is visible */
   left:-100px; /* same as above */
}
```

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/z5zjpb9e/

It's also worth noting though, that even this could be problematic if X-Frame-Options is set to SAMEORIGIN, as you won't have control over this on a remote server that you can't edit. For a more in-depth explanation [see this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options).